# Zero(0) Supported devices: "app contains no supported native platform" & "app has an unsupported framework version"

Tags: android, gradle, permissions, compatibility

I've run into the issue of 0 supported devices when publishing an app on Google Play. I've removed all of the permissions from my gradle with no different outcome, which led me to suspect something else was amiss.

Google Play support replied the following compatibility errors:

> "Your app contains no supported native platform: armeabi-v7a for Android versions 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24,  and 25 for APK version 5 (Production)"
>
> "Your app has an unsupported framework version for Android versions 17 and 18 for APK version 5 (Production)"

I only managed to find two similiar cases on the issue: one suggested replacing possible apache libraries, the other was resolved by "deleting old libraries".

I've no idea where to start, my gradle doesnt have any of the packages mentioned previously as culprits, **is it related to the libraries not being the latest versions of themselves?**

Any help on explaining what these error messages mean would be appreciated.

```
 android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.abc"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 11
    versionName "1.5"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})



  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
  compile 'com.microsoft.projectoxford:emotion:1.0.355'
  compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
  compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.0'
  compile 'com.microsoft.projectoxford:face:1.0.0'
  compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.5'
  compile 'com.intentfilter:android-permissions:0.1.2'
  compile 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.2'
  compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.1.0'
  compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.1.0'
  testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
 }

Android Manifest 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.xu.servicequalityrater">
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="19"
    android:targetSdkVersion="25"/>

<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera"
    />

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"  />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera.front"
    />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />


<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/logo"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".Splash"
        android:label=""
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme_NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".CameraActivity"
        android:label=""
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme_NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name=".EmotionRecyclerActivity"
        android:label=""
        android:parentActivityName=".CameraActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme_NoActionBar">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".CameraActivity" />
    </activity>

    <receiver
        android:name=".services.HealthAlarmReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service android:name=".services.HealthPictureService2" />
    <service android:name=".services.CameraOneService" />

    <activity android:name=".TestActivity" />
    <activity
        android:name=".GraphActivity"
        android:label=""
        android:parentActivityName=".EmotionRecyclerActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme_NoActionBar"></activity>

</application>
```

Comment: show your manifest

Comment: done, but I've tried removing all permissions and pushing an APK to play store. Same issue.

Comment: Add attribute required = false on all of your use-feature tags (temporarily) and upload the apk.